# How to Enable TLS 1.2, 1.1,1.0, and SSL in iOS app?

Tags: ios, tls1.2, app-transport-security

My question is related to Apple Transport Security (ATS) and I am too much confused.

I want to support all the protocols (all version of TLS and SSL) in my swift app. If I change NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to false, will app work on all protocols by default? Or do I have to specify domain in configuration and add NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
     <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>your.servers.domain.here</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

And how can I check my app is communicating with server on what protocol?

Comment: Do you know the domain(s) you are going to be connecting to? Is the server something the user can enter so you can't know all the possibilities ahead of time?  Also, how are you connecting to the URLs? Are you using a UIWebView, WKWebview, or NSUrlConnection? The answer to you question varies based on how you plan to connect.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to read up https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

In short, you need to specify NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion to support TLS1.0 and up; 1.2+ is the default.

Why are you trying to support older, less secure protocols anyway?

I don't know how you could check which protocol is being used, but if you can configure a server to only work with, say, TLS 1.0, then your app will only connect with the TLSv1.0 key in place; and that's easy to test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have a requirement in which i have to support all the protocols. I have already read this. Just need to know how can i check my app is communicating with server on what protocol. I need to be sure on what i coded because i don't have access to server.

Comment: One way of checking which protocol is being used by a certain URL is to run in OS X terminal the following utility:

nscurl --ats-diagnostics <YOUR URL> --verbose

Comment: Thanks @miranido, this is the right way to detect the flaw in the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**Connecting Securely to a URL**

Connecting to a URL via TLS is trivial. When you create an NSURLRequest object to provide to the initWithRequest:delegate: method, specify https as the scheme of the URL instead of http. The connection uses TLS automatically with no additional configuration.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html

Comment: FYI, what that link doesn't say, is that recent iOS versions default to TLS 1.2. See other answers if need to support older versions of TLS.