# How can I integrate TLS Sockets in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, ssl, protocols

I would like to implement an application layer protocol in Swift for iOS apps. However, I need a TLS Socket as a foundation. Does anybody know how to handle that?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320980/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-1-1-1-0-and-ssl-in-ios-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Enable TLS 1.2, 1.1,1.0, and SSL in iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320980/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-1-1-1-0-and-ssl-in-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a package that accounts for the recent changes in restrictions to TLS by Apple, check it out! https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets

It is Objective-C, but worth a look still maybe?